# Движок для Online Judge

Tags: веб-программирование

Есть ли в паблике (в открытом доступе) движки для создания [подобного](http://acm.timus.ru/) рода ресурсов?

Comment: Старый неформатный вопрос с хешкода.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Система тестирования:
http://ejudge.ru/

А к ней уже веб-мордашку не проблема прикрутить.